# Multidimensional indexing and mapping

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

I see that `numpy` has many indexing facilities, but still couldn't get them to do what I need.

First, assume there are two one-dimensional arrays `A, I` of the same shape, a one-dimensional array `B` which can be indexed with elements of `I`, and a three-argument function `f`. Then the result I need can be achieved like `starmap(f, zip(A, I, B[I]))` (`starmap` and `zip` are from pure python, not `numpy`). So far, so good...

But actually, all the arrays are **two**-dimensional and I'd like get two-dimensional result as well, which is equivalent to applying the same function as above to each row of the arrays - this is what I now do in a loop.

Are there better ways to do this, than just looping?

**UPD:**

For example, with one dimensional arrays:

```
A = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(3,))
B = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(5,))
I = np.random.randint(0, 5, size=(3,))

def f(a, i, b):
    return (a, i, b)

print A, I, B
print list(starmap(f, zip(A, I, B[I])))
```

And for two-dimensional:

```
A = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(2, 3))
B = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(2, 5))
I = np.random.randint(0, 5, size=(2, 3))

def f(a, i, b):
    return (a, i, b)

print A
print I
print B
print [list(starmap(f, zip(A_row, I_row, B_row[I_row])))
       for A_row, I_row, B_row in zip(A, I, B)]
```

Comment: wrt. "Fist assume that there are..." why don't you just give us some code? Show, don't tell.

Comment: @Jaime: `f` is just a pure python function from a library which I can't change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's just a normal function, your overhead is going to be primarily function overhead. You could do the `zip` with an `hstack` or something, but it's not going to help speed-wise.

If you're just looking for a neater way of doing it, try

```
x_indexes, _ = numpy.ogrid[:len(I), :0]
numpy.vectorize(f)(A, I, B[x_indexes, I])
```

Normally a higher-level view can let you vectorize the whole thing, which will be much faster. That's worth keeping in mind if this ends up slow.

Comment: Actually, I'm not concerned about speed much in this case, as the result of this will be just printed to user - so it shouldn't be large. However, neater ways, like you suggested in this post, can make the code better in several senses. And, by the way, your code doesn't work for any case, neither single-, nor two-dimensional.

Comment: It should work now. Unfortunately it's much less pretty.

Comment: This version doesn't raise exceptions on two-dimensional case, but the output is different from the needed one (it executes `f` on the whole arrays, not elementwise). Compare with the code in question.

Comment: It depends on whether `f` returns a tuple. If it does, several arrays are returned (because `numpy` can't store tuples) so you might want to `dstack` them. If `f` just returns a number, the results are much more similar.

Comment: Oh, really - checked with numbers now. However, as in my case `f` returns a python object, it seems I should keep using loops...